# yay doesn't find package, though it exists

Tags: arch-linux

There are 3 packages that exist in the AUR that I want to install:

1. [vazir-fonts](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vazir-fonts/)
2. [vazir-code-fonts](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vazir-code-fonts/)
3. [shabnam-fonts](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/shabnam-fonts/)

But when I try to install them with [yay](https://github.com/Jguer/yay), it can't find it:

```
❯ yay vazir-fonts
No packages match search
```

I believe the reason is me not being able to connect to AUR, because when I ping archlinux.org, things are fine:

```
❯ ping -c 4 archlinux.org                                                                                                                                                                      
PING archlinux.org (138.201.81.199) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from apollo.archlinux.org (138.201.81.199): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=124 ms
64 bytes from apollo.archlinux.org (138.201.81.199): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=125 ms
64 bytes from apollo.archlinux.org (138.201.81.199): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=122 ms
64 bytes from apollo.archlinux.org (138.201.81.199): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=122 ms

--- archlinux.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 122.033/123.433/125.182/1.330 ms
```

But when I ping aur.archlinux.org, half of the packets are lost:

```
❯ ping -c 4 aur.archlinux.org                                                                                                                                                                  
PING aur.archlinux.org (5.9.250.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from luna.archlinux.org (5.9.250.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=121 ms
64 bytes from luna.archlinux.org (5.9.250.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=120 ms

--- aur.archlinux.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 2 received, 50% packet loss, time 17ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 120.115/120.734/121.354/0.710 ms
```

I also tried `torsocks`, but that doesn't work either:

```
❯ torsocks yay vazir-fonts                                                                                                                                                                     
No packages match search
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I couldn't clone yay's repository either:

```
❯ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git                                                                                                                                                  
Cloning into 'yay'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to aur.archlinux.org:443
```

So I had to manually download its snapshot from AUR in my browser and go from there.

How can I fix this?

Also, I used `nmtui` to connect to Internet.

The content of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
╰─ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search Home
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: May I ask the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: @funilrys edited the question

Comment: What if you try with another DNS server?

Comment: Try with `-S` ej: `yay -S vazir-fonts`